# jQuery referencing a div generated with a partial view to append another partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this partial view rendered multiple times on a page:

```
@model POS.Domain.Entities.Category

<div class = "category" id= "@Model.Name">
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    <a href='javascript:getView();'>Get Partial View</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getView() {
            $('#divResult').load("@Url.Action("ProductList" , "Product", new {category = Model.Name})");
        }
    </script>
    <div id="divResult">
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that when someone clicks the `Get Partial View` link, it will load the partial view generated by my `ProductList` action in my `Product` controller using the category value `Model.Name` and append that partial view to the appropriate `divResult` div.

The problem is that after the page has loaded, if a user clicks on any of the `GetPartialView` links, it loads the list of products contained within the final category and appends them to the top-most `divResult` div.

I am hoping for a bit of guidance in changing the script to use jQuery to appropriately load the information.  I also feel that I should not be repeating the script every time this partial view is loaded. . .  So how would I write the appropriate jQuery script that would do the following when the user clicks one of the `Get Partial View` links:

- get the id of the parent div of the link (`@ModelName`)
- use that id to make a call to my Action: `@Url.Action("ProductList", "Product", new {category = **that id**})";`
- append the partial view returned by that Action to a div with the id of `divResult` that is within the parent div we found two steps above this step

**Update**

Here is the Html from my view:

```
<div class = "category" id= "Balls">
    <h2>Balls</h2>
    <a href='javascript:getView();'>Get Partial View</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getView() {
            var $category = $(this).closest(".category");
            var categoryName = $category.attr("id");
            //var categoryName ="Balls";
            $('.divResult').load("/Product/ProductList",
                {category: categoryName});
        }
    </script>
    <div class="divResult">
    </div>   
</div>
<div class = "category" id= "Drinks">
    <h2>Drinks</h2>
    <a href='javascript:getView();'>Get Partial View</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getView() {
            var $category = $(this).closest(".category");
            var categoryName = $category.attr("id");
            //var categoryName ="Balls";
            $('.divResult').load("/Product/ProductList",
                {category: categoryName});
        }
    </script>
    <div class="divResult">
    </div>   
</div>
```

If I manually pass the value of `Balls` to `categoryName` - I can receive products from the `Balls` category, but if I use `var categoryName = $(this).closest(".category").attr("id");` I get `undefined`.

Maybe seeing the HTML will help?

Comment: you are not referencing the id correctly in that last part, it should be `.attr("id");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the load function to pass data along with the load request. Check http://api.jquery.com/load/

Change the getView function to as follows:

```
function getView(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var $category = $(this).closest(".category");
  var categoryName = $category.attr("id");
   $('.divResult', $category).load("@Url.Action("ProductList" , "Product")", {
     category: categoryName
    });
}
```

Update:
Same ID cannot be used for multiple elements on a page. And since you are loading the partial view mutliple times and appending you would end with multiple elements having same ID. Change your partial view to as follows(use class instead of ID):

```
@model POS.Domain.Entities.Category

<div class = "category" id= "@Model.Name">
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    <a href='/get-partial-view'>Get Partial View</a>
    <div class="divResult">
    </div>
</div>
```

and move the getView function to the parent view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getView() {
                var categoryName = $(this).closest(".category").attr("#id");
                $('.divResult').load("/Product/ProductList",
                        {category: categoryName});
        }

        $(function(){
            $(".category").on("click", "a", getView);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Two problems:  First, this does not seem to appropriately send my `category` information to my action.  Second, when I append information from the retrieved PartialView while ignoring the `category` information, it appends in the same fashion as my original code - only the top-most div gets anything, even if I click a link that was rendered in a different div.  Hmm . . .

Comment: I don't see any problem with the load function implementation. If the category name is correctly assigned as id, then it should get passed correctly. Also what are you referring to when you say " only the top-most div gets anything, even if I click a link that was rendered in a different div"?

Comment: The `categoryName` is being passed with a value of "undefined", although if I manually set the value to match the parent div ID, things work correctly.  ---- In regards to the second part.  This (the code block in the OP) is all part of one partial view that is loaded multiple times on one page.  Any time I get a successful call from one of these ajax requests, the appended data is appended only to the first `partialView` on the screen - not the actual `partialView` that I clicked the link: `Get Partial View` in.

Comment: @miscusermandude My bad. I missed the `.` in the closest method call. Regarding `loading the partial view multiple times on one page` you cannot have same id for multiple elements. Will post an answer with minor changes shortly.

Comment: We're making progress.  I am still returning undefined for `categoryName` and now the partial view is loaded at every single id on the page (because the partial view is repeated), so it seems I need to return to naming this by id, but rename the id something custom for each partial (like `divResult + @Model.Name`)

Comment: @miscusermandude I don't see why the category would be sent as undefined.

Comment: I added HTML from the view to the original question in hopes that it may clear some things up as far as why the category is being returned as `undefined`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14075/discussion-between-chandu-and-misc-user-man-dude)