# Incorrect jQuery function firing when within a parent class div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Solved** - see my answer below

---

I have a page that I want to display a list of `parentCategories` on.  When a user selects a `parentCategory` a list of `categories` appear (or sub-categories).  I then want the user to be able to click on a `category` and have a list of `products` appear.

I have made the `category` to `products` feature work on its own page using what was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541496/jquery-referencing-a-div-generated-with-a-partial-view-to-append-another-partial).

I can also make a list of `parentCategories` clickable to show a list of `categories` (or sub-categories).

The problem comes when I am trying to make the list of `products` appear after the list of `categories` have appeared.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function getCategories(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var $parentCategory = $(this).closest(".parentCategory");
            var parentCategoryName = $parentCategory.attr("id");
            $('.divResult', $parentCategory).load("@Url.Action("CategoryList", "Product")", {
                parentCategory: parentCategoryName
            });
        }

        $(".parentCategory").on("click", "a", getCategories);

        function getProducts(f) {
            f.preventDefault();
            f.stopPropagation();
            var $category = $(this).closest(".category");
            var categoryName = $category.attr("id");
            $('.divResult', $category).load("@Url.Action("ProductList", "Product")", {
                category: categoryName
            });
        }

        $(".category").on("click", "a", getProducts);
    });
</script>
```

I know it repeats itself almost identically, but I am trying to make it work before I clean it up a bit more.  The way I think it should be working is when a user clicks on a `parentCategory` link, it is within a div class of `parentCategory` so the function `getCategories` fires.  This makes a few divs within the parent `parentCategory` div containing divs of the class `category` - I would think that since I use:

```
$(function() {
    $(".category").on("click", "a", getProducts);
});
```

When I click on a link within a div of `category` the function `getProducts` should fire, but it doesn't.  Instead `getCategories` fires again (I can tell because of a `Debug.Write()` within the action that `getCategories` triggers.

After the `categories` appear under the `parentCategories`, my page is shaped kind of like this:

```
<div class="parentCategory" id="1">
. . .
    <div class="result">
        <div class="category" id="1">
        . . . 
            <div class="result">
                *This is where Products would be listed
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="category" id="2">
        . . .
            <div class="result">
                *This is where Products would be listed
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
. . .
</div>
<div class="parentCategory" id="2">
. . .
    <div class="result">
    . . .
    </div>
</div>
```

**What do I need to do so that when I click on a link within a `category` class div my function `getProducts` activates instead of `getCategories`?**

**Update**

I have tested my code with the `category` div outside of the `parentCategory` div and everything works as expected.  The issue seems to definitively be with the fact that my `category` divs are within `parentCategory` divs and:

```
$(".parentCategory").on("click", "a", getCategories);
```

seems to override the use of:

```
$(".category").on("click", "a", getProducts);
```

I apparently need to restructure something - I just don't know what.

Comment: Well for one thing, you probable want to call "e.stopPropagation()" when the `<a>` tags are clicked, to prevent the "click" event from bubbling up to the handler on its parent.

Comment: Your identifiers are not distinct, that is not the cause of the problem but NEVER use the same ids multiple times in a page

Comment: @Pointy I have added the stopPropagination(); call (doesn't fix the problem, but after reading the documentation - it certainly should be here with my structure).

Comment: @rsplak I did not know that would affect things badly if I used the same id with different classes - I will have to restructure my setup after I resolve this problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do was to change my click() functions from:

```
$(".parentCategory").on("click", "a", getCategories);

$(".category").on("click", "a", getProducts);
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click",".parentCategory", getCategories);

$(document).on("click", ".category", getProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getCategories(e) {
        //........
    }

    function getProducts(f) {
        //........
    }

    $(".parentCategory").on("click", "a", function(e){ 
         //Checking whether "a" is outside of ".category" element
         if( $(this).closest(".category").length===0 ){
             getCategories.call(this,e);
         }else{
             getProducts.call(this,e);
         }
    });
});
```